# Read Only Files in ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: read-only

Like in the title, I have some problems with read & write rights.

In this location I can read only:[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgVR4.png)

I mention that in this location Ubuntu is installed, I use dual boot and in the past time I had rights to read & write.
On desktop I can do everything I want, also in other folders.

The reason that I want to store files in that location is because I have more space (70GB) and on desktop or other folder location I have only 15GB free - I don't know why.

Can someone help me to gain access again in that location?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to that directory, right click and select 'open terminal here' and run:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 ./
```

Running through sudo will ask for your password.

Alternatively, you can open you terminal and run

```
sudo nautilus
```

this will open your file-manager with admin permissions. Now go to the desired directory. Right click and open properties where you will find the 'Permissions' tab. From there you can change the permissions to your liking.

Comment: Thank you for the info that you provided to me.

For the moment, seems that is working again. Really strange this thing.

As soon as I have the chance again, I will test what you said above.

Comment: I have again this issue mention above.
@ Maxsash I've tried first method and is not working.
On second option that you provided to me I can't access location that I want :(.

Any other opinion?

Thank you in advance.